# Can you spot the javaScript Syntax error in this code please?

Tags: javascript

Making a start with JavaScript on CodeAcademy and I cannot spot the problem here. There is apparently a syntax error and I have spent the last 30 minutes trying to find it.

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
var totalDamage=0;

while(slaying){ 
    if(youHit){
        console.log("You hit the dragon for " + damageThisRound);
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;

        if(totalDamage >= 4){
            console.log("You killed the dragon!"):
            slaying = false;
        }

        else{
            youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }

    else{
        console.log("The dragon killed you");
        slaying = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/)

Comment: Was there anything in your browser's developer console that indicated what/where the error was?

Comment: CodeAcademy should've shown you a error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Which literally means _"There's a colon (`:`) somewhere there shouldn't be."_ Ctrl+F for `:`, problem solved...

Comment: cheers, im working on a chromebook...with xubuntu installed and it all works apart from the syntax error prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You have a colon on this line:

```
console.log("You killed the dragon!"):
```

Comment: On CodeAcademy, the browser's console will not show syntax errors like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for the heads up. I assumed it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log("You killed the dragon!"):
```

Colon (`:`) instead of a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 1):

CodeAcademy should've shown you a error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

[image]

This literally means *"There's a colon (`:`) somewhere there shouldn't be."*
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `:`, replace the colon.
(See line 12 in the screenshot)